# Amd CPU ryzen supported?

Tags: release-loki, amd

I have a brand new AMD Ryzen CPU and I would like to install Elementary OS, but it is stuck at boot screen...

When will Elementary OS be compatible ?

I'm using elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20170517

This is the error I get when I try to boot.

[image]

Update:
It looks like kernel 4.9 ( this is the kernel packed with 0.4.1 ) does not have Ryzen support... only in kernels 4.11 and up have this.

Any solution now?

---

It looks like , kernel 4.9 ( this is the kernel packed with 0.4.1 ) have no Ryzen support.. only in 4.11 and up have this.

Any solution now ?

---

This is the error when i try t boot  .[image: boot error]

Comment: I am not sure it is a CPU problem but guess rather some other component of your system. You might want to try a bootable Ubuntu usb key.

Comment: I am using a Ryzen 1700 with eOS 0.4.1 just fine...

Comment: how? i cant boot it or install

Answer (score 1):

As a **workaround**, you might want to try to install 4.11 from the Ubuntu mainline kernels. 
You can download and install from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.4/ the following packages:

```
sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-4.11.4-041104_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_all.deb \
linux-headers-4.11.4-041104-generic_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_amd64.deb \
linux-image-4.11.4-041104-generic_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, buckle up your big boy pants because you are going balls deep today!

We get to play with the terminal. This guide is made assuming that you can get to the terminal [(edit) and the Desktop GUI.] Here is a list of commands that will set you up and upgrade your kernel.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ukuu`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

- Now go ahead and use UKUU to update the kernel to 4.11.3
- It will say that there are errors the first time you try this, ignore
  that.
- Reboot your computer.
- Go back to UKUU and reinstall 4.11.3 kernel
- If the install was successful, go ahead and restart your computer
  again.

Now run

`sudo apt-get purge ukuu`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

If you only have access to the terminal use this advice given from Lemonslice

As a **workaround**, you might want to try to install 4.11 from the Ubuntu mainline kernels. 
You can download and install from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.11.4/ the following packages:

```
sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-4.11.4-041104_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_all.deb \
linux-headers-4.11.4-041104-generic_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_amd64.deb \
linux-image-4.11.4-041104-generic_4.11.4-041104.201706071003_amd64.deb
```

Now restart your computer when your kernel is installed and continue on.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

- Now reboot your computer again for good measure.

When you computer has restarted go ahead and run

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

- Say yes to any prompts.
- Reboot your computer and now try your multimedia keys and possibly
  your video drivers.

I have to do this for my laptop and desktop for it to fully function. The 4.11.3 kernel is really good and has not given me issues.

So yeah, it seems like a lot, but it is not. Have confidence!

edit: realized I made the assumption you could also get to the desktop to use the GUI. The answer from Lemonslice is the way to go. I believe it takes care of a nice chunk of legwork. I added it to my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help , but it don't work .. if i don't boot with acpi=off it stuck at the same point "unexpected IRW trap at vector 07 "

Comment: Damn, maybe try setting your bios settings to default and reboot elementary after you then reset your boot order correctly.

Comment: i tried this but it refuses to boot normally.. only with acpi=off also i find this : https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/6247wx/ubuntu_has_issues_installing_to_gigabyte_ryzen/

Comment: Okay, yeah it you have a Gigabyte motherboard they tend to be a long while until they play nice with Linux. Especially bleeding edge boards. I stick to MSI as I find their motherboards reliable and unkillable. So.... yeah... if you have a Gigabyte motherboard, I will confidently say you are out of luck.

Comment: yes.. i have a x370 gaming 5 ( gigabyte ), i will wait for the fix , anyway , big thanks  for your help !